# SQL query to identify records that are effective during a certain interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a SQL query that can be used to fetch records whose effective dates falls between a given start/end date time with a catch that the effective date is valid forever until there is another record with a different effective date. For example, I am showing a price table where the product prices are effective based on certain dates

```
ProductID    EffectiveDate   Price
  Milk         01/01/2012     3
  Milk         02/01/2012     2.85
  Milk         03/01/2012     3.1
  Milk         03/15/2012     3.4
  Milk         04/01/2012     3.2
```

If my start/end date time is 03/01 and 03/31, then I want both the records that are dated 03/01 and 03/15, but if my start/end is 03/20 and 03/31, then I need to get just the record 03/15
The query I have works, however I am trying to see if there is a much efficient way in getting the desired results.

```
SELECT productid, 
       effectivedate, 
       price 
FROM   product p 
WHERE  ( p.effectivedate >= '03/20/2012' 
         AND c.effectivedate <= '03/31/2012' ) 
        OR p.effectivedate = (SELECT TOP 1 pp.[effectivedate] 
                              FROM   product pp 
                              WHERE  pp.effectivedate <= '03/20/2012' 
                                     AND pp.productid = p.productid 
                              ORDER  BY pp.effectivedate DESC)
```

The reason I am looking to improve is the table can get quite bigger and i am just showing an example here as product, however the final table has many more columns.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a structure like this, I think it is best to add in the end dates and then work from there:

```
with BetterDataStructure as (
      select p.*,
             (select min(p2.EffectiveDate) from product p2 where p2.productId = p.productId and p2.EffectiveDate > p.EffectiveDate
             ) as EndDate
      from product p
     )
select *
from BetterDataStructure bds
where bds.startDate <= '2012-03-31' and
      (bds.endDate > '2013-03-01' or bds.endDate is NULL);
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use the `lead()` function instead of a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select somefields, max(effectivedate) maxdate
from product
where effectivedate >= @startdate
and effectivedate < @TheDayAfterEndDate
and not exists
(select *
from product
where effectivedate > @EndDate)
group by somefields
```